# Cannot access request body data in nodejs / express

Tags: node.js, api, post, request

I hava a route set in nodejs / express like this :

```
const testSync = (req, res) => {
                  res.status(200).send(req.body.url)
                       }

 router.post('/test-sync', testSync);
```

and in my client I make an api request using fetch, like this:

```
   const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        redirect: 'follow',
        body: {
                 url: "some url"
              }
  };

  fetch(`http://${domainName}/api/test-sync`, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => {
          console.log(result)
    })
    .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
    });
```

I am doing this as a test to see how to use request body data. Until now , if I use this api endpoint on postman I just get an empty json. How shoud I do if I want to access the request body data ? like the `req.body.url` from my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Express?  You can put this in your router.

```js
router.use(express.json());
```

And for the request from your client you can try:

```js
const requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({url: 'someurl'})
}
```

Comment: I worked !!! Thank you so much, I have been struggling with this for some hours already. You were of real help

Comment: Great!  Glad I was able to help.